# Treeview - View shows only checked nodes, edit shows all available nodes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, treeview

I need to produce a hierarchical data-bound treeview in two forms.  The edit form contains all available nodes, with checkboxes.

[image: Editable tree view]

The read-only form is the same treeview, but containing only nodes that have been checked (as if they were the only nodes available, checkboxes not displayed).

[image]

Is there a way to do this with the same tree view, and without needing a postback to commit/fetch new data from the server?

Comment: I have the editable format already working, but we need to show the user a more collapsed format to begin with, then if they choose to Edit the selections, expand to the editable format, then when they're done, collapse back to a new summary (collapsed) format.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this with JavaScript, starting with the full form, all-options available, then on the client paring down (and removing check-boxes) for clarity and conciseness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find something close enough to my answer that I provide it as an answer to anyone else who is looking for something similar.

In my case, the gold is in the jQuery:

```
$(":checkbox:not(:checked) + a").parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();
```

While this is very specific to my implementation, it will work for me.  I'd like to see something that is more generic, that can address output from any ASP:Treeview html object.

To see this in action, have a look at my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CCDSystems/Lpwwtezz/2/)

Comment: I got the full effect I was looking for by including $(":checkbox:checked").hide();  This has been added to my Fiddle.